# Using caret as exponent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, math

I am trying to create a simple graphing calculator where a user enters a function of f (like f(x) = x^2+2x+6). Basically the javascript replaces the x in the function with some number and then evaluates the function using eval(). The problem is, I want users to be able to type x^2 instead of default javascript which would be Math.pow(x,2). I'm guessing it's going to be some regular expression but I have little experience with them and find them really confusing, personally. Is it possible to convert a statement like x^3-x^2 to Math.pow(x,3)-Math.pow(x,2) ??

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you show us what you tried so far? You can start with regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: `eval` is bad practice and is unnecessary for the task (not saying that helps or anything, it's just not a good thing to do in most cases)

Comment: `^` isn't your only problem, you have to add a multiplier operator as well (*).

Comment: This is pretty much the most popular assignment in computer science, it's well covered on the site. Using `eval` and regex is cheating, however. Google ["parse math expression in JavaScript"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=parse+math+expression+in+javascript&oq=parse+math+expression+in+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.2856j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8) and you get thousands of tutorials.

Comment: Should the user be able to type `f(x) = x^(2x + 1) + 1/(2^(2*x))`?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use a Regular Expression that looks something along the lines of

```
(.+)\^(.+)
```

This will match both selections, you then replace the instances of that string, using those matches like this.

```
Math.pow($1, $2)
```

Javascript has support for this kind of operation with the function option in String.prototype.replace

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: What about x^(y * 2 - 1) ?

Comment: "something along the lines of" was my get out of jail free card ;)

Comment: @Pointy Then AST is the way to go, I think.

Comment: @peter.petrov yes, agreed.

Comment: `Math.pow(evaluate($1), evaluate($2))` would work where evaluate is the function that parses the math. (recursive, if I failed to make that clear)

Comment: Don't forget to escape `^` > `\^`

Comment: @ToniAlmeida Of course. That was silly. Cheers for the heads up.

Comment: @JohnDoe That can be done with a little bit of help from `eval()`.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, it is possible. You can easily program it yourself if you parse what the user entered. Wherever you see x^n just turn it into Math.pow(x,n). And only then eval. 
This will work for say polynomials of one variable.

2) If you want to solve this more generally (for a broader class of math functions),
you need to come up with some grammar and build an AST from the user input.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree

Comment: I didn't (and won't) downvote but your answer really doesn't *explain* much. (The question is a little broad, of course.)

Comment: @peter.petrov You really don't give a useful answer to the question. If I asked this question, then I would expect an answer that doesn't restate what I gave as an example when I asked.

Comment: With the edit, it provides new info. I'm removing my downvote. :)

Comment: I think the asker wants to know how to turn x^n into the aforementioned, you've just told him to do it.

Comment: @DanPrince OK, maybe. I just understood this question slightly differently.